# Passing template to a function without specifying concrete type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is it possible to pass a template to a function without specifying the concrete type?

I have a base class which is a template and two different specializations of it. Here is an example of the base class:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class Dataset 
{
protected:
   std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2> > _data_buffer;
public:
   virtual void doSomething(MatrixRm& data) = 0;
}
```

Here is the first class which extends the base class:

```
class InMemoryDataset : public Dataset<MatrixRm, MatrixRm>
{
public:
    void doSomething(MatrixRm& data) override
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

And here is the second class which extends the base class:

```
class OnlineDataset : public Dataset<std::string, std::string>
{
public:
    void doSomething(MatrixRm& data) override
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to pass any of this classes to a function or a constructor of a different class. But I currently can't figure out how to do this without specifying the concrete type.

Here's how I imagine it:

```
void someFunction(Dataset* dataset)
{
    //do something with the specialization
}
```

In Visual Studio I get the following error message:

> argument list for class template "Dataset" is missing

It makes sense to me why this is not allowed but is there any way around this?

Comment: Why can't you use `template <class T1, class T2> void someFunction(Dataset<T1, T2>* dataset)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the function as template too:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void someFunction(Dataset<T1, T2>* dataset)
{
    //do something with the specialization
}

void foo() {
    InMemoryDataset inMemory;
    someFunction(&inMemory); 
    // Will call someFunction<MatrixRm, MatrixRm>(Dataset<MatrixRm, MatrixRm> *)

    OnlineDataset online;
    someFunction(&online); 
    // will call someFunction<std::string, std::string>(Dataset<std::string, std::string> *)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! someFunction will do the same thing for both types. I used a template just to separate the way the data is stored inside the Datasets. This way, I’ve to implement two functions doing the same thing, right?

Comment: @Bastian Sorry for the late answer, yes, you implement `someFunction` only once.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you can just use a non-templated base class for your interface:

```
class Dataset {
public:
   virtual void doSomething(MatrixRm& data) = 0;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2> class Dataset_impl : public Dataset
{
protected:
   std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2> > _data_buffer;
};
```

Comment: Why is one downvoting this? I thought this is quite smart:)

Comment: @Frank: https://ideone.com/w7bjsz With this he won't be able to pass Dataset type to foo function.

Comment: @nomanpouigt OP's Dataset was already abstract. So it's not like they could do that in the first place

Answer (score 1):

One idiom is to assume that `someFunction` will only every be called with  a `Dataset` object and just treat `Dataset` as a template parameter as in:

```
template<class Dataset>
void someFunction(Dataset dataset){
    // ...
}
```

Of course, this solution would generate different code for each specialization of `someFunction` for each unique type passed to it.

This idiom can implemented in a safer fashion with some template metaprogramming boilerplate as in:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_dataset: std::false_type{};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct is_dataset<Dataset<T1, T2>>: std::true_type{};

template<class Dataset>
std::enable_if_t<is_dataset<Dataset>::value, void>
someFunction(Dataset dataset){
    // ...
}
```

This code defines the metafunction `is_dataset` to effectively perform a compile time check is the passed `Dataset` template is, in fact, an actual `Dataset` object.

As you seem to be aware, `Dataset*` is not a real type (or even an incomplete type). It simply provides an interface for construction of a real type (e.g. `Dataset<std::string, std::string>`).

Comment: Thank you! Your solution has the one downside you said...the meta programming will have a performance penalty, right? This won’t be sufficient in my case.

Comment: You should not notice any runtime penalty. The only downside would be (potentially) excessive code translations (i.e. code bloat). For a very large number of `Dataset` specification you _may_ notice a compile time increase.